# aise exceptions.InvalidVersionError(version) migrate.exceptions.InvalidVersionError: mysql://database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a migration with:

```
python manage.py upgrade mysql://db connection....
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
raise exceptions.InvalidVersionError(version)
migrate.exceptions.InvalidVersionError: mysql://database
```

This is my migration:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *

meta = MetaData()


engine = create_engine("mysql://db connection")
meta.bind = engine

responsibles = Table(
    'responsibles', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('breakdown_type', String(255)),
    Column('breakdown_name', String(500)),
    Column('email', String(255)),
    Column('name', String(255))
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind
    # migrate_engine to your metadata
    responsibles.create()

def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    responsibles.drop()
```

When I try the test, it runs fine:

```
python manage.py test


Upgrading...
done
Downgrading...
done
Success
```

Comment: You are using flask-migrate? Why are you specifying the connection-string in the command (`python manage.py upgrade mysql://db connection....`)? See: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: No I'm using sql alchemy migrate

Comment: I am not completely familiar with sqlalchemy-migrate (looking for the solution together with you). You tested the script against a test- database? Can you verify that the production database has the correct version to apply the upgrade? See warning… on following page https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versioning.html

Comment: The database is the same. The sql alchemy engine is the same both for the test and upgrade commands

Comment: Can you supply the version of the repository (python my_repository/manage.py version my_repository) and the database (python test_sqlalchemymigrate/manage.py db_version sqlite:///test_migrate.db test_sqlalchemymigrate) both commands are executed from the terminal. For more information see: https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versioning.html#command-line-usage